# Win7 : Black screen when switching users / logging off with SCEP av client enabled?

Tags: windows-7, scep

Anyone out there run into this? :

Seeing Win7 Ent machines show black screen and go unresponsive when switching users or logging out while the SCEP client (Microsoft's AV client supplied with SCCM) is enabled. If I disable it, the issue goes away. Just started happening yesterday.
Ran through Windows update reset, SFC, update troubleshooter, update readiness tool, updated latest to latest video card drivers, removed updates deployed in the last round, to no avail. Issue goes away in safe mode, but in clean boot with MS services running, it still happens, so 3rd party stuff ruled out.

Engaged MS support, waiting on a call.. just wanted to know if anyone has found an easy way to fix this

TIA

Comment: Yes, we've been running into this exact same thing. Thought we were going crazy. seems to affect Microsoft the most. We've been uninstalling SCEP and replacing it with Cisco AMP since that was the plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use MpCmdRun.exe to remove definition (**MpCmdRun.exe -RemoveDefinitions -All**) and search new update definition, this solve the problem.

Comment: You, Sir, are the Hero of the Day !

Comment: also just received an email from MS support stating that av definitions version 1.271.632.0  is supposed to correct the issue; looks like another bad update.

Comment: @ShawnKeslar can you confirm that 1.271.632.0 corrects the issue

Comment: I did look at SCCM yesterday afternoon, and it looked like our endpoints were at or greater than that version. I haven't had any new reports, and I don't think we've had to manually flush any more SCEP agents, so it may be working.