# Windows 7 - Black screen at logoff / switch user

Tags: windows-7, logoff, switch-user

Since July 5, some of our Windows 7 Enterprise machines started showing black screen and becoming unresponsive at user log off / switching users. No changes have been made in our environment; nothing in common between these production computers as well. It's strange that this behavior is only observed on some PCs, others are fine. All PCs are Lenovo desktops and laptops, Win7 64-bit, SCEP installed, they have different graphics cards and different set of software installed. All have the same error message in the EventLog: 4005 - Windows logon process has unexpectedly terminated.
I'm now running an AV scan, but maybe someone noticed this issue too, or has any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for your suggestions!
Just wanted to come back on this in case someone else is struggling with this as well. While we are still researching it and are not 100% sure about the cause, looks like the issue is really SCEP-related. PCs which had definition update 1.271.5xx.0, had this issue - once they have been updated to the 1.271.643.0, issue seems to be gone.
Again, this happens not on all PCs in our company which is strange. We'll continue to look into this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling SCEP for a workaround. We have been getting these during last week and still searching for the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing the same issue.

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51216993/10052207) on another thread

"use MpCmdRun.exe to remove definition (MpCmdRun.exe -RemoveDefinitions -All) and search new update definition, this solve the problem."